# Java - Show menu from CardLayout

Tags: java, swing

I want to have a menu bar in my GUI. The menu is not visible.

```
public class GUI extends JPanel implements ItemListener{

final static String RUN_TEST = "Test 4G";
final static String SETTINGS = "Settings";
JPanel p;
JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
public GUI(){
    JFrame window = new JFrame();

    TestRun runTest = new TestRun();

    cards.add(runTest , RUN_TEST);
    cards.add(runTest , SETTINGS);

    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, RUN_TEST);
    window.setContentPane(cards);

    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem());
}
 }
```

How can I show to the user the menu "Test 4G" and "settings" so that they can change the JPanel?
Thanks for your help

Comment: You have to create two instance of TestRun, you can't add the one instance at two places in cardlayout

Comment: I have created one other instance of TestRun, the problem is still here.
Do I have to use JMenuBar and JMenuItem to switch the panel?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of using `JMenuBar` in `JFrame` and `JPopupMenu` in `JPanel` (view).

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    final static String RUN_TEST = "Test 4G";
    final static String SETTINGS = "Settings";

    private JPanel viewPanel = new JPanel();

    public MainFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        super("MainFrame");
        cretaeGUI();
    }

    private void cretaeGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setJMenuBar(cretaeMenuBar());

        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        viewPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        viewPanel.add(new Test4GView(this), RUN_TEST);
        viewPanel.add(new SettingsView(this), SETTINGS);

        add(viewPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private JMenuBar cretaeMenuBar() {
        JMenuItem testMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Test 4G");
        testMenuItem.addActionListener(this::showTest4GView);

        JMenuItem settingsMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Settings");
        settingsMenuItem.addActionListener(this::showSettingsView);

        JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("View");
        viewMenu.add(testMenuItem);
        viewMenu.add(settingsMenuItem);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(viewMenu);
        return menuBar;
    }

    private void showView(String name) {
        ((CardLayout)viewPanel.getLayout()).show(viewPanel, name);
    }

    public void showTest4GView(ActionEvent event) {
        showView(RUN_TEST);
    }

    public void showSettingsView(ActionEvent event) {
        showView(SETTINGS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MainFrame().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

аnd these are both views

```
public class Test4GView extends JPanel {

    private MainFrame mainFrame;

    public Test4GView(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;

        add(new JLabel("Test 4G"));

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                showPopupMenu(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                showPopupMenu(e);
            }

            private void showPopupMenu(MouseEvent e) {
                if(!e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    return;
                }

                JMenuItem showSettingsView = new JMenuItem("Settings");
                showSettingsView.addActionListener(mainFrame::showSettingsView);

                JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
                popupMenu.add(showSettingsView);

                popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
    }
}

public class SettingsView extends JPanel {

    private MainFrame mainFrame;

    public SettingsView(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;

        add(new JLabel("Settings"));

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                showPopupMenu(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                showPopupMenu(e);
            }

            private void showPopupMenu(MouseEvent e) {
                if(!e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    return;
                }

                JMenuItem showSettingsView = new JMenuItem("Test 4G");
                showSettingsView.addActionListener(mainFrame::showTest4GView);

                JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
                popupMenu.add(showSettingsView);

                popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand much more better the use of cardLayout. I have tried your example and it's working.